# Is there any rules of adding "please" in making requests?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, questions

There are some expressions that can be used in making requests, but I'm a bit confused about adding "please". Is the use of 'please' only possible if the sentences use modal "can and could"? and would it be possible to add "please" in  the following sentences?

1. Is it OK if I use your phone for a minute, please?
2. Would you mind if I borrowed your new camera, please?
3. I was wondering if I could borrow your novel, please.

Comment: It's up to you, but a little politeness  *(**please**)* always helps. Whatever - that's more a matter of ***social etiquette*** than "learning English". On the *learning* front you should be asking about, for example, the difference between ***borrow*** and ***lend*** (which you've got wrong, in #3, #4).

Comment: Thank you for correcting my sentences @FumbleFingers. I'd like to know whether adding "please" in those expressions is grammatically correct.

Comment: See, for example, [this link](https://prowritingaid.com/grammar/1008092/Should-I-use-a-comma-before-or-after-%E2%80%9Cplease%E2%80%9D-in-a-sentence#:~:text=Please%20is%20an%20adverb%20that,use%20a%20comma%20before%20it.) giving more details about the position of "please" in an utterance. You examples are fine. They all use the most common format ("please" at the *end* of the utterance, preceded by a comma in the written version), but it's often fine to put it at the beginning, or even "embedded" (as, for example, *Could I please borrow your camera?*).

Comment: Note that to a considerable extent, ***Is it okay..., Would you mind...*** and ***I was wondering...*** all imply "please" anyway. If the utterance includes an expression like that, it's nearly always perfectly natural to tack "please" on to the ***end*** of the request, but it would often sound a little "odd" to actually *embed* it within the request. So ***Is it okay** please if I use your phone?* isn't very natural compared to ***Could I** please use your phone?*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @FumbleFingers. It was very clear.